# Vertical align two column layout on top of 100% width image

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a scenario like this where I would like to have an image with width 100% as background. Next i want to align a two column layout text on the middle of image. I use display table cell and vertical align: middle and it is not working as expected.

[JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/a65L5mmL/2/)

Expected outcome is the two column layout is in the middle.
Note: The image must serve as background with width 100% and height scale according to browser width.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
  <img src="https://www.math.nmsu.edu/~pmorandi/math112f00/graphics/rectangle.gif" style="width: 100%; line-height: 0;" />
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;">
    <div style="display: table; vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 100px;">
      <div style="display: table-cell; width: 120px;">
        Left Column
      </div>
      <div style="display: table-cell;">
        <p>
          Right Column Top
        </p>
        <p>
          Right Column Bottom
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: would you like to center the table horizontal an vertically?

Comment: @LucaJung yup its good if u can demonstrate how to acheive both

Comment: @vincentsty check out my solution using `table` and `flexbox` display and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `flexbox` is an option it can be easily done removing the table and using this:

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
```

Note that I have removed the inline style and added in classes for illustration:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
  <img src="https://www.math.nmsu.edu/~pmorandi/math112f00/graphics/rectangle.gif" style="width: 100%; line-height: 0;" />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div style="width: 120px;">
        Left Column
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          Right Column Top
        </p>
        <p>
          Right Column Bottom
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to stick with tables, here is the solution:

1. Add `height: 100%` to `table` and `vertical-align: middle` to the `table-cell`s too for vertical alignment.
2. Add `margin: 0 auto` for horizontal alignment.

Demo below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper > div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.wrapper > div:first-child {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
  <img src="https://www.math.nmsu.edu/~pmorandi/math112f00/graphics/rectangle.gif" style="width: 100%; line-height: 0;" />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div>
        Left Column
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          Right Column Top
        </p>
        <p>
          Right Column Bottom
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?, the text is now also centered, I removed the padding-top so the cells are centered both vertically and horizontally: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a65L5mmL/3/)

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <img src="https://www.math.nmsu.edu/~pmorandi/math112f00/graphics/rectangle.gif" style="width: 100%; line-height: 0;" />
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;">
        <div style="display: table; vertical-align: middle; width:100%;text-align:center;height:100%">
            <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
                Left Column
            </div>
            <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
                <p>
                    Right Column Top
                </p>
                <p>
                    Right Column Bottom
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```